# removing and re-populating boostrapTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I want basically to refresh the data held in a table. First instantiation works just fine, but no luck after removing and re-fetching of the data.

`html`

```
<table id="tablePendByOrg" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="Date">Time</th>
                                <th data-field="Organization">Org</th>
                                <th data-field="f24hs"><24Hs</th>
                                <th data-field="f48Hs"><48Hs</th>
                                <th data-field="f48Hs">>48Hs</th>
                                <th data-field="fTotal">Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

`js` to populate after ajax call.

```
$('#tablePendByOrg').bootstrapTable({        
    data: d.Table
});
```

`js` to remove data

```
$("#tablePendByOrg tbody tr").remove();
```

And after a new call to the ajax code, I get the proper data in `d.Table` but no `tbody` are showing on the page, just the framed `th` that I set from the get go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they describe:

```
$table = $('#tablePendByOrg');
$table.bootstrapTable('load', data); // removes old data, no need to remove it by yourself
```

also the removal o all items is not to be done as you did:

<s>$("#tablePendByOrg tbody tr").remove();</s>

use:

```
$table.bootstrapTable('removeAll');
```